# GWT - motionchart /date object

Tags: gwt

I'm having problem with creating a GWT MotionChart. I want the chart to look like following:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart.html#notes

Following is my code:

```
package component.client.widgets;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.LineChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.MotionChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.MotionChart.Options;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

import component.client.SQLRunner;
import component.client.SQLRunnerAsync;

public class DashboardWidget 
{
    private HorizontalPanel containerPanel=null;
    private DataTable data=null;

    public DashboardWidget()
    {
        containerPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    }
    public HorizontalPanel getContainerPanel()
    {
        SQLRunnerAsync service = (SQLRunnerAsync) GWT.create(SQLRunner.class);
        AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<String[]> result)
            {
                Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {                           
                        String date1="1988,0,1";
                        String date2="1988,0,1";
                        String date3="1988,0,1";
                        String date4="1988,1,1";
                        String date5="1988,1,1";
                        String date6="1988,1,1";

                        DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy,M,d");
                        Date d1 = fmt.parse(date1);
                        Date d2 = fmt.parse(date2);
                        Date d3 = fmt.parse(date3);
                        Date d4 = fmt.parse(date4);
                        Date d5 = fmt.parse(date5);
                        Date d6 = fmt.parse(date6);


                        data.addRows(6);
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING,"Fruit");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "Date");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses");
                        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Location");
                        data.setValue(0, 0, "Apples");
                        data.setValue(0, 1, d1);
                        data.setValue(0, 2, 1000);
                        data.setValue(0, 3, 300);
                        data.setValue(0, 4, "East");
                        data.setValue(1, 0, "Oranges");
                        data.setValue(1, 1, d2);
                        data.setValue(1, 2, 950);
                        data.setValue(1, 3, 200);
                        data.setValue(1, 4, "West");
                        data.setValue(2, 0, "Bananas");
                        data.setValue(2, 1, d3);
                        data.setValue(2, 2, 300);
                        data.setValue(2, 3, 250);
                        data.setValue(2, 4, "West");

                        data.setValue(3, 0, "Apples");
                        data.setValue(3, 1, d4);
                        data.setValue(3, 2, 1200);
                        data.setValue(3, 3, 400);
                        data.setValue(3, 4, "East");
                        data.setValue(4, 0, "Oranges");
                        data.setValue(4, 1, d5);
                        data.setValue(4, 2, 900);
                        data.setValue(4, 3, 150);
                        data.setValue(4, 4, "West");
                        data.setValue(5, 0, "Bananas");
                        data.setValue(5, 1, d6);
                        data.setValue(5, 2, 788);
                        data.setValue(5, 3, 617);
                        data.setValue(5, 4, "West");

                        Options options = Options.create();
                        options.setWidth(1000);
                        options.setHeight(1000);

                        MotionChart chart = new MotionChart(data, options);
                        containerPanel.add(chart);
                    }
                };
                VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, MotionChart.PACKAGE);               
            }
        };
        service.getSomeStuffFromDB("","","","", callback);
        return containerPanel;
    }
}
```

However I'm getting error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 1988,0,1
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:1579)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:1049)
    at component.client.widgets.DashboardWidget$1$1.run(DashboardWidget.java:89)
    at com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.ExceptionHelper.runProtected(ExceptionHelper.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I'm assuming it has to do with the date object. Can someone please point out what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says it all: there is an unexpected argument passed to the DateTimeFormat.parse() method. You are passing dates like "1988,0,1" for a format of "yyyy,M,d" however according to the documentation for [DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html), the month code "M" spans the values 1-12.

In short, the month value in "1988,0,1" is in the wrong format. January is the lowest, and has a value of 1, not 0. Try changing the 0 to 1 for month.